# From CC InDesign file version to CS6

Tags: adobe-indesign, cs6, save, cc-2014

I have an InDesign file in CC version, but I need it in a CS6 version. Write now I don't have my CC installation so how can I convert this to CS6?

Answer (score 3):

I do not know how you expect anyone to help.

To open an InDesign CC file in a legacy version of the application, the file needs to be exported as an .idml file from Indesign CC. If you do not have inDesign CC, you won't be able to do this or open the file.

The only solution is to subscribe to InDesign CC, download the 30 day trial of InDesign CC and use that, or find someone to convert the file for you (which means they'll need all images and fonts related to the original file - careful of legal issues).

Answer (score 1):

Open the file in InDesign CC, then go File -> Save As or File -> Export and choose the file type IDML. You will then be able to open that IDML file in CS6

If you don't have access to InDesign, there is a service that can help:

[www.stokesdesignproject.com/down-save-indesign-file-service.php](http://www.stokesdesignproject.com/down-save-indesign-file-service.php)

Answer (score 1):

I just ran in to this problem today working on a class project. I found this website that will convert your InDesign CC file to an IDML file which can be opened by CS4 and later.

The website link is: http://ixsaveback.de/idsb/web/service/index_en.jsp

They request your name, email, and the file and within seconds you will receive an email with the file converted for you. I hope this helps anyone else who stumbles upon this forum post!

Comment: The website says: Afterwards you will receive an email with a link to download your converted file. The payment can be made easily using PayPal.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is Markzware's [MarkzTools](http://markzware.com/products/markztools/) for InDesign. This plugin works in CS5, CS5.5 or CS6 and allows the user to simply open higher versioned InDesign files in lower versions of the application.

Also, Adobe just released a new update, for CS6 SUBSCRIPTION-users only, which can allow InDesign CS6 people to open CC/CC2014 documents. The Markzware solution though, whom for clarity I must add I represent, works for any versions of CS6, CS5.5 or CS5.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=teBNEESheOo

edit - also wanted to add that Markzware also has a down-saving, file conversion service, for one-off jobs: http://markzware.com/support/file-conversion-service/